# Could Thymoquinone help against COVID-19?

Tags: covid-19, herbalism

A March 30, 2021 article in the Austrian site, [*MedMix*](https://www.medmix.at/thymoquinon-schwarzkuemmel-gegen-coronaviren-covid-19/) (in German) claims that [thymoquinone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thymoquinone) from [black seed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nigella_sativa) oil might be able to cure, or at least lessen the impact of, COVID-19.

It cites several references, including a May 2020 paper, [*Thymoquinone: shield and sword against SARS-CoV-2*](https://precisionnanomedicine.com/article/12984-thymoquinone-shield-and-sword-against-sars-cov-2)

Is this claim true?

Comment: Well, it looked quite bogus to me too but they published it in a non-predatory journal (apparently). In combination with the other provided publications, the science looks quite promising to me even though there aren't any clinical trials yet.

Comment: Deleted pseudo-answers in comments. Please use the lovely answer boxes that Stack Exchange provide just for this purpose.

Comment: There's a clinical trial going on in Pakistan. Supposed to finish in July this year https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/NCT04767087

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appears a plausible mechanism for Thymoquinone to be effective in treating/preventing COVID-19, and indeed as early as July 2020, it was stated that

> *"Therefore, the time is probably appropriate to move thymoquinone from experimentation on the bench to clinical testing for the Covid‐19
> pandemic."*

- Ahmad A, Rehman MU, Ahmad P, Alkharfy KM. Covid‐19 and thymoquinone:
  Connecting the dots. Phytotherapy Research. 2020 Jun 26.

Numerous authors find the potential across numerous studies, including your study and the two below.

- Xu, H., Liu, B., Xiao, Z., Zhou, M., Ge, L., Jia, F., ... & Wang, G.
  (2021). Computational and experimental studies reveal that
  thymoquinone blocks the entry of coronaviruses into in vitro cells.
  Infectious diseases and therapy, 10(1), 483-494
- Badary, Osama A., Marwa S. Hamza, and Rajiv Tikamdas. "Thymoquinone: A Promising
  Natural Compound with Potential Benefits for COVID-19 Prevention and
  Cure." Drug Design, Development and Therapy 15 (2021): 1819.

The best answer I can offer is yes it is possible that Thymoquinone may potentially be a treatment for COVID-19 (a cure is a little too strong), but I can find no evidence Thymoquinone has progressed to later-phase clinical trials, so we may never be able to answer this question. The lack of advancement of a potential treatment to a later-phase clinical trial is common for many theorized treatments, even when treatment mechanisms are demonstrated. Later stage clinical trials are expensive, and only a few of the most likely candidates will make it to published and peer-reviewed later-phase clinical trials.

Comment: Mohammed said "cures everything but death itself". Pubmed says: 1568 articles, 47 RCTs (in general), 27 in relation to Covid (0 RCTs). So indeed: yes, very promising, tasty, well tolerated, and well for sure a good idea. As in: always. But "yes" in bold here? The Q is weakly phrased already ("help"), but you jump to "treatment" (plz, clarify that tension. ).

Comment: Lots of similar theoretical papers were published about HCQ, mind you. Later [it turned out](https://journals.plos.org/plospathogens/article?id=10.1371/journal.ppat.1009212) that the mechanisms it blocks isn't the main entry route for SARS-CoV-2. I've briefly scanned the first paper you cited (Xu et al.) It doesn't even mention TMPRSS2, so I'm not surprised it hasn't generated much excitement/citations. The same actually goes for Badary et al.

Comment: @fizz agree. Yes.

Comment: (H)CQ *isn't* 'proven bad', and for ref: https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/29932232/ https://doi.org/10.3390/cells10020302 https://doi.org/10.26434/chemrxiv.12753539.v1 if that's what anyone requires

Comment: Seeing the comment below Q: https://www.medrxiv.org/content/10.1101/2020.10.30.20217364v4 (preprint caveats as usual…)

Comment: Fwiw quinones are ***well*** known to show up constantly in poorly controlled screens - they react aggressively with a lot of different biology (mostly in ways that have nothing to do with what you want)
https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acs.jmedchem.5b01009